# NFC HID MIFARE card reading

Tags: android, nfc, mifare, contactless-smartcard

I have a HID MIFARE DESFire card i'm trying to read through android. The card is ISO 14443 as far as I'm aware, but nothing I do seems to read it. I can read what I assume is a UID.

The card looks as if it is not formatted, but i'm not sure if that's part of the HID encryption. Either way, nothing i do to read it works, i've also tried formatting it but that doesn't work.

How do I state the encryption and pass through the decription code to read the payload. Some NFC apps are stating that the card is not NDEF format.

Any help is really really appreciated as I'm getting stuck.

Heres the tag info. I'm using a Galaxy S4.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What Android device are you using? Can you provide the information that e.g. [NFC TagInfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.mroland.android.apps.nfctaginfo) gives you for that card?

Comment: Hey, it's a samsung galaxy s4. I've added more info above too

Comment: What applications does the card contain? What do you want to read/write? An NDEF message? Or any existing data on the card?